# HttpInterceptor detect 401 responses

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I had a working code that called a logout() method in case of a 401 response from the server. As I have upgraded Angular from 5.2 to 7.0.3 it is not working anymore. I think it must be something with a modified HttpInterceptor interface or the many rxjs breaking changes. Right now it looks like this and throws the error below the code.

```
export class UnauthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  private session: SessionProvider;
  constructor(private injector:Injector) {}

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
      this.session = this.injector.get(SessionProvider);
      return next.handle(request).pipe(catchError(err => {
            if (err.status === 401) {
                // auto logout if 401 response returned from api
                this.session.logout();
            }
        })
      );
  }}
```

tsc throws the following error:

> src/app/interceptors/unauth.interceptor.ts:19:51 - error TS2345:
>   Argument of type '(err: any) => void' is not assignable to parameter
>   of type '(err: any, caught: Observable>) =>
>   ObservableInput<{}>'.
>   Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<{}>'.
>
> > 19       return next.handle(request).pipe(catchError(err => {

Comment: You have to return an Observable from `catchError`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello you have to return an observable with catchError like :

```
return throwError(error)
```

Comment: Thanks. Btw vscode still complains about some strange errors but tsc runs without error.

Comment: On the bottom right of VS Code is a TypeScript version number, click on it, select TypeScript version and then choose use workspace version.